# Commit as local user

Tags: git

I'm using git on my desktop computer with user name defined in --global. Now I would like to checkout project as other user. But when I did commit I found that it is done by my main user.

I did init and set local user:

```
git init
git config --local user.name "user2"
git config --local user.email "user2@aaa.aa"
```

I did clone

```
$ git clone https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/tst.git
```

Did changes, commit and push:

```
git add *
git commit -m "aaa"
git push
```

In bitbucket webpage I found that commit was done by main user. How to make commit as local user?

Comment: Why did you clone after the init? What about rerunning the config commands in the cloned repo?

Answer (score 1):

The names of these flags can be confusing, especially when you compare them to those used by package managers such as pip and npm.

`git config --local` affects the current *repository*, not the current *(local) user*. So you should run it inside the repository that you just cloned:

```
$ git clone https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/tst.git
$ cd tst
$ git config --local user.name "user2"
$ git config --local user.email "user2@aaa.aa"
```

`git config --global`, on the other hand, affects the current *user*.

`git config --system` would affect all users on the system. This is rarely what you want; I've never used it.